# Tensorflow / Windows (native) : GPU support [Could not identify NUMA node]

Tags: tensorflow

This is about running Tensorflow native on Windows with GPU support (v0.12)

While some examples work (matmul.py) and I can see a big performance difference with GPU (1.3s) versus CPU (4.4s), I do get an issue with one example:

> E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:586] Could not identify NUMA node of /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.

While others have had a problem with the library for cuDNN not being loaded, my library is correctly found and loading:

> I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\stream_executor\dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library cudnn64_5.dll locally

Does anybody have the same issue? 
Was anybody able to solve it?
Can I do something to get more logging about what is going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Although TensorFlow reports an error when [this message is produced](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/816ecb7a342c25c19daa8b19627346e1fb38e56f/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc#L579), you can probably ignore it, unless you are running in a multiple-GPU configuration with different GPUs attached to different NUMA nodes. As the [comment in the code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/816ecb7a342c25c19daa8b19627346e1fb38e56f/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc#L579) says:

```
if (numa_node < 0) {
  // For some reason the StreamExecutor couldn't get the NUMA
  // affinity of the GPU.  If this is not a multi-socket mobo with
  // GPUs local to different buses, it doesn't matter.  If it is, we
  // may run into trouble later with data transfer operations.  The
  // trouble may manifest as slower than expected performance, or
  // outright failures.
  LOG(ERROR) << "Could not identify NUMA node of " << name
             << ", defaulting to 0.  Your kernel may not have been built "
                "with NUMA support.";
  numa_node = 0;
}
```

As it turns out, the [code to discover NUMA nodes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/816ecb7a342c25c19daa8b19627346e1fb38e56f/tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc#L894) is only implemented on Linux, as it uses SysFS. If you are running a big-iron Windows server with multiple GPUs and NUMA, please let us know in a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues), so we can prioritize adding this support.