# NVIDIA cuda GPU computing questions

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I installed tensorflow-gpu on win10. I am trying a keras trainning example to test the GPU computing. I loaded all the cuda successfully but show the following:

```
Train on 60000 samples, validate on 10000 samples
Epoch 1/100
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:885] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 970M
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.038
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 3.00GiB
Free memory: 2.48GiB
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:906] DMA: 0
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:916] 0:   Y
I c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:975] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\gpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\gpu\gpu_device.cc:586] Could not identify NUMA node of /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0, defaulting to 0.  Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
```

I dont know what does the last sentense mean that can not identify NUMA node.
Also when I check nividia-smi, it shows the following:

```
c:\tools\cuda>nvidia-smi
Wed Dec 07 00:09:09 2016
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 353.54     Driver Version: 369.30         |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 970M   WDDM  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   64C    P0    31W /  N/A |   2371MiB /  3072MiB |     42%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

No running process found when I was training the data. Did I setup everthing correctly in this case?

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5968

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow / Windows (native) : GPU support \[Could not identify NUMA node\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891844/tensorflow-windows-native-gpu-support-could-not-identify-numa-node)